# Can we change the style (color) of select menu in v-data-table , By default class primary--text is applied for highlights and label

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to change the color of select (sort by) in v-data-table API ? By default class primary--text is applied for highlights and labels.

[image]

Comment: if you have a codepen, post the link, not the image

Comment: No, the image is from the link to codepen from vuetify documentation itself https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables